# VBA in Word: CopyAsPicture method ignores text size as well as some font faces

Tags: vba, ms-word

The CopyAsPicture method in VBA in Word (I am using Word 2010 and 2016) is to transform a given piece of text (some string selected in the document) into a picture.

Microsoft provides this sample script in its tutorials:

```
Sub CopyPasteAsPicture()

'Origin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.copyaspicture

 ActiveDocument.Content.Select
  With Selection
   .CopyAsPicture
   .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
   .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
 End With
End Sub
```

For testing the CopyAsPicture method I used however the following script which I found in a related question in this forum:

```
Sub CopySelPasteAsPicture()
' Take a picture of a selection and paste it at the document end

' Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888145/convert-text-to-image-in-microsoft-word

With Selection
    .CopyAsPicture
End With

ActiveDocument.Content.Select
With Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .TypeParagraph
    .TypeParagraph
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
End With

End Sub
```

**I tested this but I find two problems with it:**

1) Text size is ignored. Text sized, say, 28 pt will be rendered in the resulting picture as 12 pt or something like that

2) Not all font faces get recognized. I have some special fonts (both in otf and ttf) that I want to picturize that way. These fonts are ignored, and instead I get a picture of a standard font (Times New Roman or whatever).

I do not find help for these issues in Microsoft's VBA documentation.

**Additional information:**

1) Why do I want to do this? I use some rare fonts that people do not have usually, and including them into the .docx also does not work reliably. I have to share these documents with colleagues, and they should be able to see also the characters from the special fonts.

2) Picture generation works with cyrillic characters in standard fonts. That's good so far.

3) Picture generation also works with fonts that have cliparts instead of pictures (such special fonts are  used e.g. for childrens books or textbooks for people to train reading and writing)

4) The font that in my case does not get picturized (but replaced by pictures of some standard system font) is a font I got as .otf, but I transformed it to .ttf (because I thought I could then include into the documents, but this did not work either). - I did so far not test if it would work with the original otf, but I doubt it because there was so far no problem with ttf versus otf fonts.

**Question:**

I would like to understand **why** font size and some font faces are ignored.

Of course, ideas how to solve this are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
```

A metafile picture is meant to retain font data. So when the document is opened on a device that doesn't have that font Word will follow its font substitution rules. I also vaguely recall that there is a font related bug in the metafile format.

I suggest that you play with the other [paste data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpastedatatype) and see what works best for you.

Comment: You put me on the right way. I tested all the datatypes (leaving out those that seemed clearly irrelevant such as wdPasteHyperlink and wdPasteHTML). I had bad luck with all of them (including wdPasteBitmap, wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap, wdPasteShape). I wanted to give up but tested out of mere stubborness also **wdPasteOLEObject** and what? Indeed, this gives a usable result also with my exotic font.

Comment: ... However, there is a follow-up problem: The picture box that is pasted has full-page width (even when there is only one letter displayed). This box can be resized via its mouse handles (the letters keep their size), but that may cause a lot of work. Question therefore: is there a way to automatically make the picture frame fit the size of the actual picture?

Comment: That should really be asked as a separate question. Essentially you would need to determine the maximum width of what you are copying and then set the OLE object to that width.

Comment: The golden rule when creating documents is to only use fonts that you can guarantee all users will have installed. I realise that is not what you want to hear, but there it is. You can find lists of fonts that are installed with each version online.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann The problem with using an OLE object is that the OLE Server is required on all machines where the document is opened. The OLE Server is responsible for displaying the content of an embedded OLE object. In this case, if the resulting object is a Word document embedded in another Word document it might work as the document will be opened in Word. However, if the font is not available on the target machine the recipient may still not see what you hope/expect. A screen shot might be your best bet...

Comment: @m4o_tim  Using standard fonts: yes of course, that's common wisdom. However, as shortly mentioned in the question, the special fonts I am dealing with do not show normal letters of any living language, rather pictogrammes. And I have to share this with my colleagues who cannot install fonts on their systems because of restrictions set by their employers. Therefore, transforming those "letters" to pictures seems to be a possible solution.

Comment: @CindyMeister  Thank you. This was indeed an important hint. I have to check how the documents look on other machines (as compared to on my own).